# System.Windows.Form location unexpected offset

Tags: c#, winforms

If I create a form like this:

```
using (var form = new Form())
{
    Recorder videoRecorder = null;

    // create the form
    form.Text = "Test ScreenCastRecorder";
    form.Height = form.Height = 297;
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    form.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

and I make a screenshot of my screen and copy it in notepad, then the location of the form is (7, 0) and not 0, 0.
[image]

Why?

How to get the real location?

Comment: It is the border.  Which is transparent on Win10 and 11, note how the mouse cursor changes when you move it close to the visible edge.  Consider this.RectangleToScreen(this.DisplayRectangle) to work from the client area of the window, inflating it to crop the image to your liking.

Comment: You are right!! Is that